How to wrap one object around another?

I've been trying a couple of different ways to get an object that has depth to wrap around a boot as a sort of strap. I've tried shrink wrapping a plane then adding depth, tried to shrink wrap normally, tried to parent it to a plane and deform to the plane while shrink wrapping the plane, and now trying to conform. I'm not sure how to achieve what I want to do.

Create a curve that turns around the calf:

Create a plane, give it the following modifiers: Array (Fill Type > Fit Curve), Curve, Shrinkwrap, Solidify:

Apply the modifiers and move the edges so that the faces don't overlap:


Thank you so much, that is so helpful. The step by step guide is really appreciated!
